# React 17 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <a> in <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have read through the existing solutions and still cant seem to get it to work.

components/NavBar.tsx

```
import { Box, Link } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import NextLink from "next/link";

interface NavBarProps {}

const NavBar: FunctionComponent<any> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Box {...props} bg="tomato" w="100%" p={4} ml={"auto"} color="white">
      <NextLink href="/login">
        <Link mr={4}>Login</Link>
      </NextLink>
      <NextLink href="/register">
        <Link>Register</Link>
      </NextLink>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

index.tsx

```
import NavBar from "../components/navbar";

const Index = () => (
  <>
    <NavBar></NavBar>
    <div>hello world</div>
  </>
);

export default Index;
```

Error Screenshot
[Error Messsage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB1j7.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try

`<NavBar/>`

instead of

`<NavBar></NavBar>`

Comment: Nope, did not work either!